# UIImage representations in virtual memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, virtual-memory

I have a number of calls to `[UIImage imageNamed:]` and I know the caching keeps the bitmaps allocated in virtual memory.

However I have a number of small images such as buttons and icons and the total data size is not anywhere near the virtual memory allocations in the ImageIO region.

How large do images become once fully mapped in virtual memory?

How are images placed in Interface builder referenced? Via file URL or cached in VM?

Answer (score 1):

If the image is mapped as a bitmap. then its size will be width * height * size per pixel. So if you have a 10 * 10 image that is 24 bytes per pixel. then it'll be 240 bytes in memory.